# How to make sure only one checkbox is enabled in selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have scenario in my code
Once I click on  a checkbox in page,I will get a popup for it, which contains  some 5 checkboxes.

Here,I am getting all the checkbox elements and putting in a list.

But,I have to implement here, only one checkbox should be enabled.
Once I enable a check box ,i need to validate all other are disabled in that popup window.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: If you are ready to use ruby selenium binding use WATIR which sits in the top of selenium binding and also give the html to verify or HTML page.

Comment: Place the HTML, Is your pop-up is the part of the web page ?

Answer (score 1):

use `isEnabled()`, which will check whether given WebElement is enabled or not :

```
boolean enabled = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the checkbox")).isEnabled();
```

if you want to check whether the checkbox is checked/selected or not, use `isSelected()` method as:

```
boolean checked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the checkbox")).isSelected();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's logic how you can verify that only one checkbox can be selected at a time using Java and TestNg assert:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox -> {
    checkbox.click();
    for (WebElement element:driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"))) {
        if (element.equals(checkbox))
            continue;
        Assert.assertFalse(element.isSelected(), "Other checkbox should be not checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can please give it ruby with RSpec

Comment: I'm not ruby guy but I'll try if have time. Hope you understood logic I tried to explain